Menu Icon WPF C# doesn't seem centered
It looks like when one uses MenuItem.Icon, the Icon is not centered and there is no HorizontalAlignment property. More specifically, the icon is slightly too much to the "left".

Here is a MRE to reproduce this without having to download any file.
XAML Code:
<Window x:Class="MREStackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="HelloWorld Window" Height="300" Width="400">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_New">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/20190530/ourmid/pngtree-correct-icon-image_1267804.jpg" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>

Code behind:
using System.Windows;

namespace WPFHelloWorld
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

It looks like adding the HorizontalAlignment="Center" property to the MenuItem Control does not help either (which I guess makes sense since it would relate to its positioning relative to its parent element).

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5367587/Improved-WPF-MenuItem-Template

That's exactly the issue I'm facing, although this seems more of a dirty very complex hack, is there no "official" fix or at least a fix that "isn't too complicated"? I'm very new to programming so I'm not sure I'll be capable of handling such things.

"Image" has a Margin; shift the (image) icon right with: Margin="2,0,0,0" (for example).

@GerrySchmitz that worked although it made the image smaller. And playing with the Width property made it cropped https://i.imgur.com/TtT5d4g.png which is weird

Then try: Margin="2,0" ... which adds "2" to the right (as well as left). If that doesn't work, think "bigger". e.g. which "parent" might be constricting its "child". And / or use the "Live Visual Tree" and "Live Property Inspector" to learn more about what's happening.
